# Refresh/Update/Requery an access Report daily with new data

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, refresh, updates

I am trying to write some VBA to update a report with the most current data daily from a table. This report collects all the data from this table and shows it in a presentable manner but I don't want it to grab previous days data, only update from 12:00am to 12:00pm for instance every day, then incorporate this with my code to export this report as a pdf (which already works, but just shows the whole table constantly). It should be possible as my report has dates that are stored as values, I just don't know how to go about it with If statements etc. Here is my code for a module that is connected to a macro that is automatically run daily.

```
Function Reportmacro()
On Error GoTo Reportmacro_Err
   
   Dim fpath As String
    ' Check for year folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("H:\TEST\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "H:\TEST\" & Year(Date)
    End If

     ' Check for month folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("H:\TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "H:\TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False)
    End If
    
    ' Check for day folder and create if needed
    fpath = "H:\TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Day(Date)
    If Len(Dir(fpath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir fpath
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Changeover Car Report", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", fpath & "\" & "CCReport" & Day(Date) & "_" & Month(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) & ".pdf", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    End If
    
    
Reportmacro_Exit:
    Exit Function

Reportmacro_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Reportmacro_Exit

End Function
```

For some more background: My table includes a ChangeoverID, Formdate(a date that a corresponding form is completed then recorded in table), Formtime(same as form date but just time), CardID(card scanner id), EmployeeID, CarID, etc. I suppose the time here wont matter because I am aiming to get it reported daily, hopefully without changing the original table, just the report code?

Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Open report filtered to date/time range then OutputTo the open report.

Comment: Are you saying this VBA procedure is called by a macro? An autoexec macro?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is because your report itself is not filtered. Try changing the report itself to have a default filter of Formdate = Date -1, which I assume is how you are determining which information counts as "Yesterday."

The other alternative is to open the report with a WhereCondition, then output the open form, then close it. All of that can be done in VBA with a single function. If you need help writing that function, let me know and I'll edit this post.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies guys, I have actually found a solution based on what most of you said. I ended up thinking about a filtering option for my report (especially since I just wanted to grab specifics without manipulating the raw data itself) Going into the report layout view I found the option to sort by date by right clicking the field and selecting one of the many options... "today" was one of them. Then I had the issue of this filter not being loaded on start up of the report... So I enabled that in the properties view which makes everything work as intended! Filter is loaded on startup, every day and the report is auto generated to save on a network share. Thanks for your help, it did lead me on the right track.